# canvas tag drawing lines problem.... 

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas tag, I use it draw lines on that, 
the canvas is a square.
I use "space" to record the space between two lines.
and I have canvasWidth and canvasHight to record the canvas size, actually, they are the same numnber....320

```
        var x=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            x = parseInt(x + space);

            myCanvas.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
            myCanvas.fillRect(x, 1, 1, canvasHeight);
            myCanvas.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
            myCanvas.fillRect(1, x, canvasWidth, 1);

        }
```

I can use the draw all the red lines on the canvas, 
but the green lines only can draw two on the canvas, other just can't appear, 
I used try {}catch , and it is no error disappear.

Comment: I find there is a problem, when the Y-Axis is bigger than 150 will not display the elements... ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using?

The problem does not seem to be in the code you've shown, because it works fine for me.

Here is my example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="320" width="320" />

<script language="javascript">
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
var space = 10;
var x=0;
var canvasHeight = 320;
var canvasWidth = 320;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x = parseInt(x + space);

    myCanvas.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
    myCanvas.fillRect(x, 1, 1, canvasHeight);
    myCanvas.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
    myCanvas.fillRect(1, x, canvasWidth, 1);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use parseInt, is your space variable has type of string? If not, try to remove parseInt.

Comment: I removed it, it still can't draw the all green lines.